# I don't understand how functions work (processing)

Tags: processing

I don't understand how to create a function and have been reading on possible examples on how to put my cat face to repeat in a nested loop format, but I can't seem to figure out how to make it work. I need to repeat the face of my animal on a static row and then randomize it with a for function. Though I really don't understand how to even create a simple addition function. I'm not sure if this is even correct but if anyone can send me some links or hands on examples of how to make it work I would appreciate it. I don't know if this should be an array or some class function to make it repeat.

```java
void cat()
{
strokeWeight(4);
//ears
fill(236,229,206);
triangle(260, 270, 260, 175, 320, 230);
triangle(390, 230, 450, 175, 440, 270);
fill(241,212,175);
triangle(270, 270, 270, 200, 330, 250);
triangle(395, 240, 440, 195, 430, 280);
//whiskers
fill(236,229,206);
ellipse(350, 300, 200, 150);
//nose
fill(10);
triangle(330, 300, 350, 320, 370, 300);
line(310, 340, 350, 320);
line(350, 320, 390, 340);
//eyes
fill(0, 0, 0);
ellipse(310, 270, 10, 10);
ellipse(390, 270,10, 10);
}

void setup() 
{
size(800,800);
background (255);
cat();
}

void draw()
{

for (int i = 0; i<10; i++)
{
for (int j = 0; j<8; j++)
{
cat();

}
}
}
```

Ignore the cat on the bottom. I didn't know how to make it work as a loop function and just wrote it there for placement. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to answer general "how do I do this" type questions. You'll have better luck if you isolate your problem in a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and try to ask a more specific question. That being said, I'll try to help in a general sense.

The best thing you can do is [break your problem down into smaller pieces](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/how-to/program) and take on each step one at a time. Try to get something simple working: create a function that draws a single circle, and then call that function with different arguments to draw multiple circles. Get that working before you try to draw a more complicated shape. Then if you get stuck, you can ask a more specific technical question.

Shameless self-promotion: [here](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/creating-functions#writing-functions) is a tutorial on creating functions in Processing.

Comment: No, I appreciate the plug in. That does sound like a good idea though this is due tomorrow night and I'm not sure if I have time with my other assignments I need to do. Would I be able to make void cat into an int of some kind to repeat the face? Or do you believe this code is wrong entirely and it would be better if I make another animal face like with ellipses and make them similar to your red target as global variables? I'm sorry to bother you but i can't seem to get an answer that is very helpful from my teacher or TA's.

Comment: @JordanOrtiz Honestly, the best thing you can do is start with something simpler. That might sound like it's more work, but in the long run it will save you time. You aren't going to get much further if you keep trying to hammer away at code you don't fully understand, which is why I'm recommending you start with a simpler example. Get it working with a single circle. When you have that working, it will be much easier to add your cat logic into your simple function than it will be to try to change all of your logic directly in your main sketch. Good luck.

Comment: Yeah, I understand. Thank you very much. Could I ask for a recommendation on where I could start looking for examples? Would your page have any "for" functions so I can get an idea of how to start?

Comment: @JordanOrtiz Sure, [here](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/for-loops) is a tutorial on `for` loops. But honestly, don't worry about that yet. Get it working with a simple function first.

Comment: Yes, of course. I have a test coming up as well on for loops so this will help me study for the test later this week. Thank you again for your time